# BigQuery CSV Import: Allow Jagged Rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to import a CSV to a BigQuery table from the user interface. My import job fails with the message:

```
Too many errors encountered. (error code: invalid)
gs://foo/bar.csv: CSV table references column position 15, but line starting at position:29350998 contains only 15 columns. (error code: invalid)
```

I'm assuming this means the importer doesn't like null fields in source data without an actual `null` string. Is there a way to make the UI allow jagged rows on import? Or, if not, what CLI command should I use to import my CSV file to a table this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI has an `Allow jagged rows` checkbox that you can select. Did you try that? It's part of the `Options` for the `Create Table` wizard.

Comment: Thank you! I was doing automatic schema detection so I missed that option.